# how to write 301 redirects when code to remove index.php is present (EE7)

Tags: redirects

I am trying to create simple same-domain redirects for an EE7 site on Dreamhost using the htaccess file. For instance, I want to redirect https://www.example.com/template_group/page1 to https://www.example.com/template_group/page2. I have tried:

`Redirect 301 /template_group/page1 /template_group/page2`

This works in terms of going to the right page, but the resulting url is not as desired:
https://www.example.com/template_group/page2?/page1

The standard code to remove "index.php" is present:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/innersys/. [NC]
RewriteRule (.?)index.php/(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]`

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

When I remove the above from the .htaccess file the redirect behaves as expected, as long as I change the redirect to:

`Redirect 301 /index.php/template_group/page1 /index.php/template_group/page2`

With the code to remove index.php present I have tried:

`RewriteRule ^template_group/page1$ /template_group/page2? [L,R=301,NC]`

and also:

`RewriteRule ^template_group/page1$ /template_group/page2? [L,R=301,NC,qsd]`

But each yield the same result (added query) as:

`Redirect 301 /template_group/page1 /template_group/page2`

I have been adding the above code BELOW the opening "RewriteEngine On" and ABOVE the code to remove index.php.

With the standard code to remove "index.php" present how do I write the redirect for https://www.example.com/template_group/page1 to https://www.example.com/template_group/page2 and have the resulting URL be as intended ( https://www.example.com/template_group/page2 )?